# Check Writer: Getting the program to display values 10-19 as words

Tags: c++

So I am doing the Check Writer program, and am having trouble with some parts. Most of it works except when printing out a data input such as $12.45 it will say two dollars and 45 cents instead of twelve dollars and 45 cents. Now I added an if statement to make the program display it as twelve dollars, but the new data being printed is now twelvetwo dollars and 45 cents. So my trouble is with coming up with something to ignore the next piece of data if the data before that begins with a 1.

```
#include "TextVersionOfNumber.h"

string TextVersionOfNumber::getTextVersionOfNumber()
{
string one_19[] = { "", "one", "two", "three", "four",
    "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
    "eleven", "twelve",
    "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen",
    "eighteen", "nineteen" };

string twenty_90[] = { "","","twenty","thirty","forty",
    "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

int thousand = amount / 1000;
int hundred = (amount / 100) - (thousand * 10);
int ten = (amount / 10) - ((thousand * 100) + (hundred * 10));
int one = (amount)-((thousand * 1000) + (hundred * 100) + (ten * 10));
int t_alt = ((ten * 10) + one);
int cents = (amount * 100) - ((thousand * 100000) + (hundred * 10000) + (ten * 1000) + (one * 100));

if (thousand >= 1)
{
    cout << one_19[thousand] << " thousand ";
}
if (hundred >= 1)
{
    cout << one_19[hundred] << " hundred ";
}
if (ten > 1)
{
    cout << twenty_90[ten] << " ";
}
else if (ten = 1)
{
    cout << one_19[t_alt];
}
if (one >= 1)
{
    cout << one_19[one] << " dollars";
}
if (amount < 1)
{
    cout << "0 dollars";
}
if (cents >= 1)
{
    cout << " and " << cents << " cents";
}
else if (cents < 1)
{
    cout << " and 0 cents";
}
/*cout << thousand << endl;
cout << hundred << endl;
cout << ten << endl;
cout << one << endl;
cout << cents << endl;
cout << t_alt << endl;*/


return string();
}
void TextVersionOfNumber::setAmount(double _amount)
{
amount = _amount;
}
```

Comment: You might find the `℅` operator useful - it gives you the remainder on division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You risk outputting 'one' twice:

```
if (ten > 1)
{
    cout << twenty_90[ten] << " ";
}
else if (ten = 1)
{
    cout << one_19[t_alt]; // <- still, one could be != 0!!!
}
if (one >= 1)
{
    cout << one_19[one] << " dollars";
}
```

Try it this way:

```
if (ten == 1)
{
    cout << one_19[t_alt] << ' ';
}
else
{
    if(ten > 1)
    {
        cout << twenty_90[ten] << ' ';
    }
    if (one >= 1)
    {
        cout << one_19[one] << ' ';
    }
}
if (amount < 1)
{
    cout << "0 ";
}
cout << "dollars";
```

Additionally, "dollars" was not outputted if (only) last digit was 0.

Comment: Ah Thank You! That makes a lot of sense seeing it written out.